# Magento 2.3 Save and Duplicate Product

Tags: magento2, product, seo, save, duplicate

I wanted to make a duplicate product. SO i did save and duplicate and a product was created. 
For product 1,SEO url is gin-glasses-pasabahce-timeless
For product 2 , SEO url is gin-glasses-pasabahce-timeless-1

On my site, only the first product is accessible and not the second one.
What can be the issue.

Comment: Have run reindex, cache commands?

Comment: @aravind yes ............

Comment: check the product in the Website tab section for the duplicate product.

Comment: The duplicate product will be is disabled state. Please enable and check.

Comment: There should be no issue, Agnes is right, the duplicated product is by default in disabled state so you have to enable it first to make it accessible.